# Is five days of daytime temperatures between 45-60F sufficient to cure Quikrete placed around the base of a wooden fence post?

Tags: concrete

I need to secure some fence posts that were knocked over by a big falling branch during a two-week period of heavy rains a couple of months ago. The ground was sodden at the time so the posts are intact. Neighbor only recently had his tree wired with steel cables to support some other big branches overhanging the fence, and I wanted to wait until that work was complete before commencing repairs on the fence. However, the weather has changed and temperatures are dropping to near or a little below freezing at night. There are five days of 45-60F daytime temperatures coming our way. Would that time be enough for Quikrete to cure sufficiently for a fencepost application, if the night-time temperatures drop below 40F?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the book (ACI 306R), structural concrete can withstand one freeze thaw cycle after it has reached 500 psi compressive strength. After that one cycle, it must be protected from additional freeze thaw cycles until compressive strength reaches 3500 psi, so you're racing to reach 3500 psi. The time until 3500 psi varies with the final strength of the concrete. For 3500 psi, Type I concrete, it will take 28 days at 73°F to reach 3500 psi. For 5000 psi, Type III concrete (high early strength), it will take 3 days at 73°F to reach 3500 psi. 40°F is the threshold temperature below which no curing occurs.

Since you presumably have no reinforcing steel, calcium chloride as an accelerator is fine in your case. A calcium chloride accelerator lowers the 40°F zero-curing threshold. A calcium chloride accelerator at 2% by weight cures with 53°F ambient temperature as though it was 73°F. Just limit it to 2%, though. Bad stuff happens at higher doses. Such accelerators plus insulation are the usual strategies for placing concrete in the cold.

Before going nuts with all sorts of complexity, consider the mechanics of your post bases. The role of the concrete is to broaden the bearing width beyond the post's 3-1/2" or 5-1/2" natural bearing width. Compacted crushed rock would provide the same functionality, where terribly fissured concrete can be interpreted as very well consolidated crushed rock. You probably would get good performance even from failed concrete.

**Solutions**

- Place 5000 psi, Type III concrete with 2% calcium chloride accelerator and pile some leaves up on the footings to better retain the hydration process's exothermic heat. Mind your water cement ratio, as too much water will lower the 5000 psi final strength and delay reaching the 3500 psi finish line. As long as you're jumping through so many hoops, an air entrainment admixture would be a good idea for your application. All of this complexity seems silly for your application, but knock yourself out if you want to go "by the book."
- Delay placing the concrete until next year. If your neighbor is cooperative, then you can embed the posts in 6" of gravel at the base and then tether the posts on both sides of the fence down to stakes. Build the fence with these tethered posts and worry about placing the concrete next year.
- What I would do? I would dig an extra 6" for my posts anticipating that the hydration heat provides sufficient curing temperature for the concrete below the top 6". I would use 5000 psi, Type III concrete and mix with water pretty dry to avoid losing much strength to a bad water/cement ratio.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestions. I've never mixed concrete in the cold weather and didn't know what to expect.

Comment: If daytime temperatures are that high, the ground won't freeze.  I suspect as long as the OP keeps the surface of the concrete above 40º (heat blanket?) for the period needed to reach 500 psi, he'll be fine.  I suspect addtitives and high early strength concrete will be hard to come by for him...

Comment: @Huesmann, my local Lowes has high early strength concrete. Seasonally, stocking the stuff should be normal because it's the correct material for this time of year.

Answer (score 3):

Holding up fence posts is not something that needs concrete to cure perfectly.  The strength comes more from making sure that it stays moist and doesn't dry out before it cures since the curing comes from a chemical reaction and not drying out.  I'd think you'll be fine.  If you're concerned, cover it with something to stay above freezing (with mild below-zero temps it'll keep enough warmth from the ground that it won't freeze).